# Chrome/Chromium makes unity effects laggy,when used with nvidia proprietary driver

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, google-chrome, chromium

When chrome is under load,unity effects is laggy.

This is nvidia driver issue.

Turning off hardware acceleration is a way to solve it, but it creates screen tear.

Is there any workaround?

```
nvidia driver:367.57
cpu-i3 2100
```

Comment: Is it a laptop? And what is "under load"?

Comment: its a desktop.if u have 4 or 5 tab loading in google chrome, then press super+w.then u will see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. disable hardware acceleration

Settings > Advance Settings > System > uncheck the hardware acceleration

2.enable smooth scrolling for screen tear and scrolling lag

Go to: chrome://flags/#smooth-scrolling and Enable it.